# ¿Por qué no sale la pila invertida en el main si dentro del procedimiento si se invierte?

Tags: c++, pilas

No entiendo por que no sale la pila invertida en el main si dentro del procedimiento si se invierte y la estoy pasando por referencia

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Pila {
   int dato;
   Pila *prox;
};

Pila* crearPila(int valor){
    Pila *nuevo = new Pila;
    nuevo->dato = valor;
    nuevo->prox = NULL;
    return nuevo;
}

bool PilaVacia(Pila *pila){
    return pila==NULL;
}

int Tope(Pila *pila){
   if (!PilaVacia(pila))
      return pila->dato;
   else   
       return -111;    
}

void Apilar(Pila **pila, int valor){
   Pila *nuevo = crearPila(valor);
   nuevo->prox=*pila;
   *pila=nuevo;
}

void Desapilar(Pila **pila){
     if (!PilaVacia(*pila))
        *pila=(*pila)->prox;
     else
       cout<<"Pila vacia imposible desapilar "<<endl;
}

void mostrarPila(Pila *pila){
    while (!PilaVacia(pila)) {
        cout <<Tope(pila)<< "  ";
        Desapilar(&pila);
    }
}

void invertirPila(Pila **pila){
    Pila *pila_auxiliar = NULL;
    while (!PilaVacia(*pila)) {
        Apilar(&pila_auxiliar, Tope(*pila));
       Desapilar(*&pila);
    }

    while (!PilaVacia(pila_auxiliar)) { //   <--- aqui se invierte y funciona pero 
        Apilar(*&pila, Tope(pila_auxiliar));
     Desapilar(&pila_auxiliar);
    }
}

main(){
     int cantidad,i,valor;
     Pila *pila = NULL;
     cout<<"Indica cantidad de elementos a ser colocados en la pila: ";
     cin>>cantidad; i=0;
     while (i != cantidad) {
         cout << "Indica valor a colocar: ";
         cin>>valor;
         Apilar(&pila,valor);
         i++;
     }
     
     cout<<"Pila Original: "<<endl;
     mostrarPila(pila);
     invertirPila(&pila);
     mostrarPila(pila); // <<---aqui sale igual, pareciera que no se invierte
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función `invetirPila` realmente no invierte la pila original. La inversión se produce correctamente en tu pila auxiliar, pero es revertida en el segundo ciclo `while`. Si tu entrada al programa son tres enteros, 3, 2 y 1, en tu función ocurre esto:

```
                           ESTADO INICIAL
_____________________________________________________________________

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                                               ╔═════════╗
║    1    ║                                               ║  Vacía  ║                                              
╠═════════╣                                               ╚═════════╝ 
║    2    ║
╠═════════╣
║    3    ║
╚═════════╝
```

---

```
                         PRIMER CICLO WHILE
_____________________________________________________________________

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║    2    ║  -> Desapilar -> ║    1    ║ ->   Apilar  ->  ║    1    ║
╠═════════╣                  ╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝
║    3    ║                  
╚═════════╝

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║    3    ║  -> Desapilar -> ║    2    ║ ->   Apilar  ->  ║    2    ║
╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝                  ╠═════════╣ 
                                                          ║    1    ║                  
                                                          ╚═════════╝

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║  Vacía  ║  -> Desapilar -> ║    3    ║ ->   Apilar  ->  ║    3    ║
╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝                  ╠═════════╣ 
                                                          ║    2    ║                  
                                                          ╠═════════╣
                                                          ║    1    ║
                                                          ╚═════════╝
```

Tu pila auxiliar efectivamente esta invertida con respecto a la original. Si tu función simplemente retornara una nueva pila invertida, bastaría con retornar tu pila auxiliar. El problema viene ahora:

```
                         SEGUNDO CICLO WHILE
_____________________________________________________________________

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║    3    ║  <-   Apilar  <- ║    3    ║ <- Desapilar <-  ║    2    ║
╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝                  ╠═════════╣ 
                                                          ║    1    ║                  
                                                          ╚═════════╝

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║    2    ║  <-   Apilar  <- ║    2    ║ <- Desapilar <-  ║    1    ║
╠═════════╣                  ╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝
║    3    ║                  
╚═════════╝

 Pila orig                                                 Pila aux
╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗                  ╔═════════╗
║    1    ║  <-   Apilar  <- ║    1    ║ <- Desapilar <-  ║  Vacía  ║ 
╠═════════╣                  ╚═════════╝                  ╚═════════╝ 
║    2    ║
╠═════════╣
║    3    ║
╚═════════╝
```

Como ves, el segundo ciclo hace la operación inversa del primero y tu pila queda como al principio. En esencia, cada vez que desapilas los elementos de una pila y los apilas en otra inviertes el orden de estos elementos. Si repites esta operación un numero par de veces te quedas igual que empezaste.

Por tanto, una forma muy obvia (aunque no necesariamente la mejor) de solucionarlo es intercalar otra pila auxiliar, por ejemplo:

```
void invertirPila(Pila **pila){
    Pila *pila_auxiliar1 = NULL;
    Pila *pila_auxiliar2 = NULL;

    while (!PilaVacia(*pila)) {
        Apilar(&pila_auxiliar1, Tope(*pila));
        Desapilar(*&pila);
    }
    
    while (!PilaVacia(pila_auxiliar1)) {
        Apilar(&pila_auxiliar2, Tope(pila_auxiliar1));
        Desapilar(&pila_auxiliar1);
    }
    
    while (!PilaVacia(pila_auxiliar2)) {
        Apilar(*&pila, Tope(pila_auxiliar2));
        Desapilar(&pila_auxiliar2);
    }
}
```

Existen varias posibilidades aparte de la anterior, otra opción usando solo operaciones de apilado y desapilado y solo pilas como estructuras auxiliares es:

- Almacenas el primer elemento de la pila original en una variable temporal.
- Pasas el resto de elementos a una pila auxiliar.
- Apilas el elemento de la variable auxiliar en tu pila.
- Pasas todos los elementos de la pila auxiliar a tu pila original.
- Repites los pasos anteriores pero dejando los elementos ya invertidos en tu pila original, hasta invertir la pila completamente.

Usar una aproximación recursiva también es común en este problema. La idea es que podemos **substituir las pilas auxiliares por la propia pila de llamadas**, en vez de almacenar temporalmente los elementos en nuestra propia pila auxiliar se usa la pila de llamadas para ello. Al igual que en la versión iterativa **se necesita hacer uso de la pila de llamadas dos veces (dos funciones recursivas) para invertir la pila**.

Se suele afirmar que la recursion permite invertir la pila sin usar memoria adicional, lo cual no es estrictamente cierto. La pila de llamadas también ocupa espacio, la diferencia por tanto es mas bien en que parte de la memoria almacenamos los datos temporales.

Dependiendo de las limitaciones que tengas o te impongas, como si puedes usar otras estructuras auxiliares como arrays, tienes otras posibilidades de abordar el problema.

Comment: Gracias @FJSevilla por la aclaratoria ahora puedo resolver el problema. Por otro lado creo me conviene hacerlo recursivo.